# using pickerInput in r shiny to apply function

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets, pickerinput

I would like to be able to apply a function to a given set of columns from the `RLdata10000` dataset.  I have been going through shiny tutorials and am attempting to learn how to use `observeEvent` and `actionButton`.  However, I would like to be able to pick the columns I use so I came across `pickerInput`.    In short, I would like to be able to pick a set of columns from `RLdata10000`, and apply the function via `actionButton`.

My problem is that I get an error:  `Error: unused argument (RLdata10000)`.  My code is below.  I would like to be able to do this with two data files eventually.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(RecordLinkage)

data(RLdata10000)

cleanup <- function(x){
  x <- as.character(x) # convert to character
  x <- tolower(x) # make all lowercase
  x <- trimws(x, "both") # trim white space
  return(x)
}

ui <- basicPage(
  h2("Record Linkage Data"),
  actionButton(inputId = "clean", label = "Clean Data")
  pickerInput(width = "75%",
  inputId = "pick_col1",
  label = "Select columns to display",
  choices = colnames(RLdata10000),
  selected = colnames(RLdata10000),
  options = list(
    `actions-box` = T,
    `selected-text-format` = paste("count > ", length(colnames(RLdata10000)) - 1),
  `count-selected-text` = "Alle",
  liveSearch = T,
  liveSearchPlaceholder = T
),

multiple = T)
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$clean, {
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    lapply(input$pick_col1, cleanup)
  })
 }
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't actually able to replicate the error you noted, but you had a few issues that were preventing you from getting what (I think) you're after.

**First**, you were missing commas in the UI after the `actionButton` and `pickerInput` elements.

**Second**, you are only giving `lapply` the names of columns - not the data - when you use `input$pick_col1`, so your cleanup function has nothing to work on. Using `select` from `dplyr` provides a simple way to name the columns and get the data too.

**Last**, `renderDataTable` wants a table format as an input (i.e., either a data frame or a matrix), but `lapply` produces a list. You need to convert the output of `lapply` into a workable class.

From these three changes, updated code would look like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(RecordLinkage)

data(RLdata10000)

cleanup <- function(x){
  x <- as.character(x) # convert to character
  x <- tolower(x) # make all lowercase
  x <- trimws(x, "both") # trim white space
  return(x)
}

ui <- basicPage(
  h2("Record Linkage Data"),
  actionButton(inputId = "clean", label = "Clean Data"),
  pickerInput(width = "75%",
              inputId = "pick_col1",
              label = "Select columns to display",
              choices = colnames(RLdata10000),
              selected = colnames(RLdata10000),
              options = list(
                `actions-box` = T,
                `selected-text-format` = paste("count > ", length(colnames(RLdata10000)) - 1),
                `count-selected-text` = "Alle",
                liveSearch = T,
                liveSearchPlaceholder = T
              ),

              multiple = T),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$clean, {
    output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
      data.frame(lapply(select(RLdata10000, input$pick_col1), cleanup))
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is really great and helpful.  Thanks for laying out my missteps so clearly.